# Assigning multiple row in case statement

Tags: oracle

I have this query

```
select devlocview.ENTERPRISENAME
FROM AlarmDeviceView alrmDevView
INNER JOIN devicelocationview devLocView 
    ON devlocview.oid=alrmdevview.deviceoid
LEFT OUTER JOIN DEVICEGROUPVIEW devGrpView 
    ON devlocview.oid=devgrpview.deviceoid
LEFT OUTER JOIN RackCapacityView rackCapView 
    ON devlocview.RACKID=rackCapView.oid
WHERE 
(
    alrmdevview.createddate = ( select max(alview.createddate) 
                                from alarmdeviceview alview 
                                WHERE alview.alarmoid=alrmdevview.alarmoid) 
    or alrmdevview.createddate IS NULL
)
AND devlocview.ENTERPRISENAME='Enterprise1'
AND devlocview.buildingname in (
CASE
WHEN $p{building} IS  not NULL THEN $p{building}
WHEN $p{building} IS  NULL THEN (select buildingname from cdmr.devicelocationview)
END
)
```

Here this part `"select buildingname from cdmr.devicelocationview"` returns multiple rows due to which I am getting

> exception as 01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than
>   one row"

As per the requirement I want to assign multiple building when `$p{building} is  null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CASE` is a scalar expression, it must evaluate to a scalar value.  You can't use it to return a multi-row set.

The most common idiom I've seen for varying the condition based on whether an input value is NULL would look like this for your example:

```
AND (  ( $p{building} IS NOT NULL AND devlocview.buildingname = $p{building} )
       OR
       ( $p{building IS NULL AND devlocview.buildingname IN (SELECT buildingname FROM  cdmr.devicelocationview ) )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
AND 1 = case 
         when $p{building} IS  not NULL 
         and devlocview.buildingname = $p{building}
         then 1
         when $p{building} IS NULL
         AND  devlocview.buildingname in (select buildingname from cdmr.devicelocationview)
         then 1
         else 0
        end
```

instead of

```
when devlocview.buildingname in (
CASE
WHEN $p{building} IS  not NULL THEN $p{building}
WHEN $p{building} IS  NULL THEN (select buildingname from cdmr.devicelocationview)
END
)
```